# Google Closure Compiler JSDoc annotations in Sublime Text or Atom editor

Tags: sublimetext, google-closure-compiler, sublime-text-plugin, atom-editor

Does Sublime Text or Atom editor have plugin for Google Closure Compiler JSDoc annotations? Especially, code completions or error checking features like in [WebStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/closure-syntax/)?

Answer (score -1):

For Sublime Text, try [DocBlockr](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs). From the [readme](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs#adding-extra-tags):

> typing `@` inside a docblock will show a completion list for all tags supported by JSDoc, the Google Closure Compiler, YUIDoc or PHPDoc. Extra help is provided for each of these tags by prefilling the arguments each expects.

Also take a look at [sublime-google-closure-snippets](https://github.com/closureplease/sublime-google-closure-snippets).

Comment: DocBlockr provides completion only for annotations, not source code completion based on annotations. sublime-google-closure-snippets are snippets for Google Closure Library.